# Why does $\ln|\cot x|=\ln|\cos x|-\ln|\sin x|$ hold?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

I am learning trigonometry. I can solve simple trigonometric equations. But its integration with log always confuses me.

I am thinking about this sums since last two hours but can't find the solutions. Can anyone kindly solve this for me?

> Use the properties of logarithm and trigonometric identities to verify the identity
>   $$\ln|\cot x|=\ln|\cos x|-\ln|\sin x|$$

Comment: Do you remember an identity involving $\ln(x/y)$?

Answer (score 5):

Use the formula $\ln \frac ab=\ln a - \ln b$

Comment: ...and also $\left|\frac a b\right|=\frac{|a|}{|b|}$.